# IsVisible in CaliburnMicro not linking

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

in my Shell view XAML

```
    <Grid>

....///
    <StackPanel x:Name="SettingsPanelIsVisible" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6" Orientation="Vertical" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button 1"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Button 2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and in my ShellViewModel

```
....//
public bool SettingsPanelIsVisible { get; set; }
```

as I understood these should be bound and the visibility should be toggled by caliburn.Micro by setting or resetting the bool, however this is not working, even though the other components are seeming to work fine

Comment: i dont think there is an automatic convention about visibility with name of stackpanel

Comment: OK, so I made a property in the ViewModel Called "StackPanelVisible" of Type Visibility and Set "{Binding path=StackPanelVisible }" but that is not working either

Comment: hum i think you have right about the name convention, i have tested and its ok, it seems your error is coming from the definition of the property. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

hum i just read StackPanel have some convention name, you error is maybe coming from your definition of viewmodel class ( dont see the code):

you have to put in viewmodel:    `using Caliburn.Micro;`

```
public class ShellViewModel:Screen or PropertyChangedBase
{
     private bool _SettingsPanelIsVisible;
     public bool SettingsPanelIsVisible
    {
        get => _SettingsPanelIsVisible;
        set
        {
            _SettingsPanelIsVisible = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SettingsPanelIsVisible);
        }
    }
    :
}
```

this convention is ok with Grid or StackPanel and maybe WrapPanel.....